# Razor doesn't take the value from the view model for Input of Date type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my model I have a field that is a date, in my view I use the following to edit it:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, new { type = "date"})
```

While I get the proper value back in the Controller when the form is submitted, initial value is not properly set in the view (it's empty)

My view model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

I cannot really find what am I missing here...

Comment: you should try creating an custom html helper for date input type. something like `@Html.DateBoxFor`. see this link for howtos - http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: see this link to creating custom strongly typed html helper - http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/389747/Custom-Strongly-typed-HtmlHelpers-in-ASP-NET-MVC